# Agrupar dois campos na mesma tabela com mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

Estou tentando montar uma query, onde eu possa imprimir o nome do corretor e a porcentagem de venda referente à ele. Quando agrupo por nome_corretor1, o campo nome_corretor2 não agrupa e vice-versa, quando agrupo ambos não é realizado o agrupamento.

**Tabela Dados_venda**

[image: Tabela Dados_venda]

**Query agrupando por nome_corretor1**

```
SELECT 
    v.nome_corretor1, v.nome_corretor2,
    ( COUNT(v.nome_corretor1)/ ( SELECT count(vt.idDados_venda) FROM Dados_venda vt) ) * 100 as Pcorretor1,
    ( COUNT(v.nome_corretor2)/ ( SELECT count(vt.idDados_venda) FROM Dados_venda vt) ) * 100 as Pcorretor2
FROM 
    Dados_venda v
GROUP BY
     v.nome_corretor1
```

**Resultado**
[image: Query agrupando por nome_corretor1]

**Query agrupando por nome_corretor2**

```
SELECT 
    v.nome_corretor1, v.nome_corretor2,
    ( COUNT(v.nome_corretor1)/ ( SELECT count(vt.idDados_venda) FROM Dados_venda vt) ) * 100 as Pcorretor1,
    ( COUNT(v.nome_corretor2)/ ( SELECT count(vt.idDados_venda) FROM Dados_venda vt) ) * 100 as Pcorretor2
FROM 
    Dados_venda v
GROUP BY
     v.nome_corretor2
```

**Resultado**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Query agrupando por nome_corretor1 e nome_corretor2**

```
SELECT 
    v.nome_corretor1, v.nome_corretor2,
    ( COUNT(v.nome_corretor1)/ ( SELECT count(vt.idDados_venda) FROM Dados_venda vt) ) * 100 as Pcorretor1,
    ( COUNT(v.nome_corretor2)/ ( SELECT count(vt.idDados_venda) FROM Dados_venda vt) ) * 100 as Pcorretor2
FROM 
    Dados_venda v
GROUP BY
     v.nome_corretor1,
v.nome_corretor2
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você tem dois corretores por venda?

Comment: @FleuquerLima, em uma venda pode acontecer de ter mais de um corretor envolvido, em casos de parcerias por exemplo.

Comment: Não é melhor na cláusula `FROM` fazer 2 selects em cima da `Dados_venda`(um pra cada corretor) e depois fazer join?

Comment: @DH, poderia exemplificar? Eu não compreendi o que você quis dizer, é possível fazer um join na mesma tabela:

Comment: Não é melhor vc ter uma tabela CORRETOR, uma VENDA e uma terceira VENDAxCORRETOR? Onde você linka todos os que participam dessa venda? Já que você que uma venda pode ter mais de um corretor e um corretor participa de mais de uma venda, isso seria uma caso de muitos para muitos, geraria uma nova tabela - isso seria uma melhor pratica e mais fácil para você relacionar.

Comment: Olhando por cima essa tabela não parece seguir as regras de Normalização; Talvez fosse interessante você conferi-las.

Comment: Algo tipo assim `SELECT ... FROM Dados_venda C1, Dados_venda C2`, e aí ficaria um puxando informação do corretor 1 e o outro do 2, mas olhando essa tabela por cima, ela não tem PK?

Comment: @DH.  Ela tem chave PK mas não dos corretores, ela relaciona com Dados_cliente, Dados_imovel

Comment: As duas primeiras querys deveriam retorna erro , no seu group by, tem coisa errada ai.

Comment: @FleuquerLima. Agora existem tabelas separas conforme vc mencionou, a tabela corretor na tabela venda uma FK, mesmo assim não está agrupando. SELECT
    c.nome_corretor1, c.nome_corretor2,
    COUNT(c.nome_corretor1) as Vcorretor1, 
 COUNT(c.nome_corretor2) as Vcorretor2
FROM 
N Dados_corretor c
GROUP BY
     c.nome_corretor1,
c.nome_corretor2

Comment: Entrei a solução, agora funcionou normalmente como esperado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução encontrada no momento, foi a união dos campos através de duas querys:

```
SELECT 
    c.nome_corretor1 as corretor,
    ( COUNT(c.nome_corretor1)/ ( SELECT count(vt.idDados_corretor) FROM Dados_corretor vt) ) * 100 as percentual
FROM 
    Dados_corretor c
GROUP BY
    c.nome_corretor1
UNION

SELECT 
    c2.nome_corretor2,

    ( COUNT(c2.nome_corretor2)/ ( SELECT count(vt2.idDados_corretor) FROM Dados_corretor vt2) ) * 100 as Pcorretor2
FROM 
    Dados_corretor c2
GROUP BY
 c2.nome_corretor2
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]